# MySQL Update table from another, ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql

Thanks for all the help in advance!

I have 2 tables: payments and payment_options. Payments is set during checkout but is linked to payment_options via `user_id`.

Here is a sample of payments:

```
# id,   user_id, order_id, subtotal, tax,  tip,  total, payment_method, payment_details
641481, 736471,  641851,   14.88,    1.32, 1.86, 8.06,  Credit Card,    ending in
641431, 109351,  641801,   10.54,    0.94, 1.32, 2.80,  Credit Card,    ending in
641381, 734171,  641751,   22.02,    1.95, 2.75, 26.72, Credit Card,    ending in
641351, 722321,  641711,   17.48,    1.55, 3.00, 22.03, Credit Card,    ending in
641201, 721511,  641581,   18.14,    1.61, 2.27, 22.02, Credit Card,    ending in
```

Sample of Payment_options (Sample Info, tokens, cc_masked, etc, year all made up):

```
# id,  user_id, cc_type, cc_token,            cc_masked,        cc_exp_month, cc_exp_year,
13371, 736471,  Visa,    fo7i-zr1w-9rsw-c6ty, XXXXXXXXXXXX3821,  7,            2015
9951,  109351,  Visa,    r3t6-co2i-i0ao-xz8d, XXXXXXXXXXXX9405,  4,            2016
9941,  734171,  Amex,    bd86-96t0-3j0g-a88g, XXXXXXXXXXX3004,   8,            2017
9931,  722321,  Maste,   o6ow-td7c-lfk0-b47e, XXXXXXXXXXXX5818,  1,            2016
9921,  721511,  Visa,    ysjp-5o4w-n3ls-y1ix, XXXXXXXXXXXX5297,  3,            2017
```

What I want to accomplish is combine the `cc_type` and `cc_masked` into Table `payments` so it looks like:

```
# id,   user_id, order_id, subtotal, tax,  tip,  total, payment_method, payment_details
641481, 736471,  641851,   14.88,    1.32, 1.86, 8.06,  Credit Card,    Visa ending in 3821
641431, 109351,  641801,   10.54,    0.94, 1.32, 2.80,  Credit Card,    Visa ending in 9405
641381, 734171,  641751,   22.02,    1.95, 2.75, 26.72, Credit Card,    Amex ending in 3004
641351, 722321,  641711,   17.48,    1.55, 3.00, 22.03, Credit Card,    Master ending in 5818
641201, 721511,  641581,   18.14,    1.61, 2.27, 22.02, Credit Card,    Visa ending in 5297
```

The problem occurs is that some people have MULTIPLE cards saved. Since `payment_options` allows for non-unique `user_id`. If I do a straight up update from one table to another where `user_id` = `user_id`, I'm afraid that values will be overwritten.

```
select `id`, `user_id`, `name`, cc_type, cc_masked,
    (select count(*) 
    from payment_options
    where user_id = count_table.user_id
    group by `user_id`)
    as count
from payment_options as count_table having count > 1
```

Here is a result:

```
# id,  user_id, cc_type, cc_masked,         count
15551, 736471,  Visa,    XXXXXXXXXXXX3821,  2
15741, 736471,  Visa,    XXXXXXXXXXXX5708,  2
15961, 510911,  Master,  XXXXXXXXXXXX3770,  2
16491, 510911,  Amex,    XXXXXXXXXXX3005,   2
```

As you can see, `user_id = 736471` has multiple Visa cards saved. `payments` and `payment_options` can only be associated by `user_id`.

This leads me to believe that I cannot just update the table 1:1 but need some kind of clause to NOT update rows where `user_id` has multiple cards saved to avoid erroneous updates

EDIT : for clarity.

As per @VMai I'm going to work with the following MySQL Query, just posting to double check

```
    SELECT CONCAT(cc_type, ' ending in ', RIGHT(cc_masked, 4)) 
    FROM paymen_options
    WHERE payment_options.user_id NOT EXISTS = (
          SELECT payment_options.user_id, (SELECT COUNT (*)
                 FROM payment_options
                 WHERE payment_options.user_id = count_table.user.id
                 GROUP BY user_id)
                 AS count
            FROM payment_options as count_table
            HAVING count > 1
          )
    );
```

Does this seem right? Workbench is giving me an error 1064 near NOT EXISTS which I'm trying to fight now.

Comment: I really tried but I don't understand what your desired result should be. Please add it. And please add some lines so one can see the multiple cards problem too.

Comment: I just updated my question to make it more clear what my end result should be. Thank You.

Comment: Are you using PHP? I could help with a script.

Comment: But how can you identify the payment option that the user used by the orderid? If you can do that then it's not difficult at all.

Comment: @adey_888 : I am using PHP so a script would be super helpful but I'm not very good as I'm just starting with the language.

Comment: @VMai : No, I cannot identify by order_id. During the checkout process, the token is called from payment_option but isn't stored anywhere. So I cannot relate an order_id to the payment_options.id that was used.

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(cc_type, ' ending in ', RIGHT(cc_masked, 4)) FROM paymen_options;` does it, if you can identify the payment option ...

Comment: And which one will you use if there's more than one?

Comment: @VMai : Thanks for the SELECT, but I still need to leave off any possible doubles. If there are doubles, it should not be touched in any way. That part I will have to do manually from cross referencing order totals vs. credit card merchant batches.

Comment: You could do that with a WHERE clause that restricts the update to those user_id values that have only one payment option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Unable to test so run a copy of your DB and backup!

```
// uses PHP Database Objects (PDO) - will need adapting for use with mysqli instead
// add your host, database, username and password below
$db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. $DB_HOST .';dbname='. $DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);

$select_query  = 'SELECT user_id, CONCAT(cc_type, ' ending in ', RIGHT(cc_masked, 4)) AS cc,';
$select_query .= '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment_options WHERE user_id = count_table.user_id GROUP BY `user_id`) AS count ';
$select_query .= 'FROM payment_options AS count_table HAVING count = 1';

// use LIMIT in SQL statement if large tables,
// otherwise your PHP script might timeout if you try to do too much

$SELECT = $db_connection->prepare($select_query);
$SELECT->execute();

$UPDATE = $db_connection->prepare('UPDATE payments SET payment_details=:payment_details WHERE user_id=:user_id');
$count = 0;
$success = true;

while($row = $SELECT->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $UPDATE->bindValue(':payment_details', $row['cc'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $UPDATE->bindValue(':user_id', $row['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $UPDATE->execute();

    if($UPDATE->errorCode() != 0) {
        echo "error: ".$UPDATE->errorInfo()[2]."<br><br>";
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
    $count++;
}
if($success)
    echo "<b>SUCCESS!<b>";
else
    echo "<b>FAILED!<b> (see error message above)";

echo "<br><br>Updated ".number_format($count)." rows!";
```

Comment: I'll make this as the answer because of your hard work but I don't want to run your script blind, even if it works as I'm trying to learn a bit more. Thank you, however, as this will be of great help in the near future.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps and was what your were looking for. Appreciate that there's quite a bit going on here but if you work through the code you should figure out what is happening. It's using two PDO prepared statements: **1)** SELECT all user_ids and cc info where there is only one payment method (all others are ignored; **2)** an UPDATE in a loop to update the payments data with the info from the SELECT. Let me know if you need any further clarification, otherwise go ahead and mark as Answer :)